# Gulp Error: Assertion Error [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified

Tags: javascript, sass, gulp

I am new to javascript I was trying to run some repositories from GitHub, I have installed all the necessary updates also done `npm audit --force` but still I am getting this error. Any help will be appreciated.

Code :

```
PS D:\agario clone\agar.io-clone-master> npm start

> agar-clone@1.0.0 start D:\agario clone\agar.io-clone-master
> gulp run

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
    at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (D:\agario clone\agar.io-clone-master\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:10:3)
    at Gulp.task (D:\agario clone\agar.io-clone-master\node_modules\undertaker\lib\task.js:13:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\agario clone\agar.io-clone-master\gulpfile.js:13:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at requireOrImport (D:\agario clone\agar.io-clone-master\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\shared\require-or-import.js:19:11) {
  generatedMessage: false,
  code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
  actual: false,
  expected: true,
  operator: '=='
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! agar-clone@1.0.0 start: `gulp run`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the agar-clone@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\cordt\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-27T11_34_53_151Z-debug.log
```

Here is my gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var util = require('gulp-util');
var mocha = require('gulp-mocha');
var todo = require('gulp-todo');
var webpack = require('webpack-stream');
var fs = require('fs');


gulp.task('build', ['build-client', 'build-server', 'test']);

gulp.task('test', ['lint'], function () {
    gulp.src(['test/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(mocha());
});

gulp.task('lint', function () {
  return gulp.src(['**/*.js', '!node_modules/**/*.js', '!bin/**/*.js'])
    .pipe(jshint({
          esnext: true
      }))
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default', { verbose: true}))
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('fail'));
});

gulp.task('build-client', ['lint', 'move-client'], function () {
  return gulp.src(['src/client/js/app.js'])
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(webpack(require('./webpack.config.js')))
    .pipe(babel({
      presets: [
        ['es2015', { 'modules': false }]
      ]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('bin/client/js/'));
});

gulp.task('move-client', function () {
  return gulp.src(['src/client/**/*.*', '!client/js/*.js'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./bin/client/'));
});


gulp.task('build-server', ['lint'], function () {
  return gulp.src(['src/server/**/*.*', 'src/server/**/*.js'])
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('bin/server/'));
});

gulp.task('watch', ['build'], function () {
  gulp.watch(['src/client/**/*.*'], ['build-client', 'move-client']);
  gulp.watch(['src/server/*.*', 'src/server/**/*.js'], ['build-server']);
  gulp.start('run-only');
});

gulp.task('todo', ['lint'], function() {
  gulp.src('src/**/*.js')
      .pipe(todo())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});

gulp.task('run', ['build'], function () {
    nodemon({
        delay: 10,
        script: './server/server.js',
        cwd: "./bin/",
        args: ["config.json"],
        ext: 'html js css'
    })
    .on('restart', function () {
        util.log('server restarted!');
    });
});

gulp.task('run-only', function () {
    nodemon({
        delay: 10,
        script: './server/server.js',
        cwd: "./bin/",
        args: ["config.json"],
        ext: 'html js css'
    })
    .on('restart', function () {
        util.log('server restarted!');
    });
});

gulp.task('default', ['run']);
```

I am using this repo if you want to take a look at it? https://github.com/huytd/agar.io-clone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have FOUND this helpfull for migration to Gulp@4.0.0

https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-migrate-to-gulp-4/